# Scale heatmaps of different dimensions to make cells equal in size

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I'm using Python package Seaborn to plot matrices as heatmaps to PDF document, each heatmap on a separate page. Heatmaps have the same column count (same within one run, but not constant in general) and possibly different row counts, so the PDF pages get different sizes. I would like heatmap cells to be squares of equal size throughout the whole PDF document. Ideally, I would specify cell size explicitly upon drawing heatmaps, but it seems there is no such option. I tried resizing the figure proportionally to row and column counts, but even for constant `figure_width` and `figure_height = cell_size * row_count` it doesn't result in cells of fixed `cell_size`, while `figure_width = cell_size * column_count` and `figure_height = cell_size * row_count` additionally creates an interplay between width and height of the heatmap (since cells are square, i.e. aspect ratio is 1:1) and the resulting scale becomes even more obscure.

Is there any solution to specify cell size in seaborn.heatmap (or matplotlib colorbar, colormesh etc.) excplicitly, or force it to certain value otherwise?

My code when `figure_width` is constant (20in) and `figure_height = cell_size * row_count` (`cell_size` is 0.2in), producing last heatmap (with 5-cell height) with cell size different from the rest:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import seaborn
import numpy as np

with PdfPages('test.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    column_count = 150
    for row_count in [100, 30, 10, 5]:
        data = np.random.rand(row_count, column_count)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 0.2 * row_count))
        seaborn.heatmap(data, square=True, xticklabels=range(column_count),
                             yticklabels=range(row_count), cbar=None)
        plt.tight_layout()
        pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
```

My code when `figure_width = cell_size * column_count` and `figure_height = cell_size * row_count` (`cell_size` is 0.2in), producing all the heatmaps with different cell sizes:

```
with PdfPages('test.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    column_count = 150
    for row_count in [100, 30, 10, 5]:
        data = np.random.rand(row_count, column_count)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(0.2 * column_count, 0.2 * row_count))
        seaborn.heatmap(data, square=True, xticklabels=range(column_count),
                             yticklabels=range(row_count), cbar=None)
        plt.tight_layout()
        pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
```

Ideally, solution should be parametric with respect to `column_count`, since it remains constant only within one PDF document, while changing throughout the runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to calculate some parameters to obtain the desired result.
You may start with the figure width. Then define some margins around the heatmap and the number of rows (which should be constant).
From those numbers you can calculate the size in inches of once cell (pixel).
Then for each plot you can calculate the figure height needed to host a certain number of cells. This is done inside the loop. Also each figure needs to have the relative margins (calculated from the absolute ones) being set.

At the end this would give (ignoring the pdfpages, which seem irrelevant here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
import numpy as np

####  Free input parameters ####
cols = [100, 30, 10, 5]
# start by specifying figure width and margins
figwidth= 20. #inch
marg_top = 0.7
marg_bottom = 0.7
marg_left = 0.7
marg_right = 0.7

# number of cells along width
cells_in_row = 150

####  Automatic calculation ####
# determine cell size in inch
cellsize = (figwidth-marg_left-marg_right)/float(cells_in_row)
# now loop over cols:
for cells_in_column in cols:
    # calculate figure height in inches
    figheight = cellsize*cells_in_column+marg_top+marg_bottom
    # set figure size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figwidth, figheight))
    # adjust margins (relative numbers) according to absolute values
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom =marg_bottom/figheight ,top=1.-marg_top/figheight,
                        left=marg_left/figwidth, right=1.-marg_right/figwidth)

    data = np.random.rand(cells_in_column, cells_in_row)
    seaborn.heatmap(data, square=True, xticklabels=range(cells_in_row),
                         yticklabels=range(cells_in_column), cbar=None)
    fig.savefig("fig{}.png".format(cells_in_column))
```

Of course you could also start with a given `cellsize` and calculate the figure width from it:

```
# start by specifying cell size and margins
cellsize = 0.08 #inch
marg_top = 0.7
marg_bottom = 0.7
marg_left = 0.7
marg_right = 0.7

# number of cells along width
cells_in_row = 150
# determine figure width
figwidth = cellsize* cells_in_row + marg_left+marg_right
```

Comment: I've just realized that "column_count" and "row_count" would make better names for "cells_in_row" and "cells_in_column", respectively, and changed the names to avoid even greater confusions (than the one caused by this change).

Comment: How do I choose the "baseline" figure width, so that the solution works for any `column_count`? Should I pre-select some `cellsize` and initialize figure width as `column_count*cellsize`? I cannot go with constant width of a figure because when `column_count` becomes too big, the x-labels will overlap due to insufficient horizontal space.

Comment: You could also start with a given cellwidth and calculate figure width from it. I updated the answer. This approach will not work with any size or any `cells_in_row` because the maximum figure width is 50 inch.

Comment: The code you show is the code you are asking about. I gave you an answer, which takes into accound figure margins. If you don't use my answer, how should I help you?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't lead to heatmaps with equally-sized cells in some cases.

`cellsize = 0.2`
`cells_in_row = 150`

`cells_in_column = 100`
`data = np.random.rand(cells_in_column, cells_in_row)`
`seaborn.heatmap(data, square=True, cbar=None)`
`fig.show()`

`cells_in_column = 10`
`data = np.random.rand(cells_in_column, cells_in_row)`
`seaborn.heatmap(data, square=True, cbar=None)`
`fig.show()`

These two heatmaps differ in cell size, even though both are calculated for based on 0.2in cell and every margin being 0. Do you know why does this discrepancy appear?

Comment: I'm sorry for weird formatting, I was not able to write proper code in the comments. The point I was trying to make is that a 10 x 150 heatmap and a 100 x 150 heatmap, calculated with the same dimensions in mind (cell size 0.2in and zero margins) and according to your logic, still differ in cell size (and in width).

Comment: You said about accounting for figure margins, but every margin being 0 is a particular case of it, right? And for this particular case your code doesn't produce the same-sized cells in heatmaps.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. When setting `cellsize = 0.2` and `margin_<i> = 0.0`, all produced images do have the same width and cell size, right? The width is 3000 pixels because 150(cells)*0.2(inchpercell)*100(dpi) =3000.

Comment: No, when setting `cellsize = 0.2` and `margin_<i> = 0.0`, the produced images do not have the same cell size. You could use your code and see for yourself. While cell size is the same in `fig10.png` and `fig30.png`, `fig5.png` has slightly smaller cells, and `fig100.png` has them even smaller.

Comment: P.S. After setting `cellsize = 0.2`, I also set `figwidth = cells_in_row * cellsize`.

Comment: The code above works fine. You have to insert the second bit inside the section `Free input parameters` of the first. This is tested using matplotlib 2.0.2 and seaborn 0.8.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. In my original code, `plt.tight_layout()` was messing the output. However, when I switched to your code which didn't have PDF output, the resulting PNGs were scaled by the viewer to fit on the screen, and this is how I saw different cell sizes.